# Homomorphsim preimage of a principal ideal still principal

Tags: ring-theory

If $\phi : R \rightarrow R'$ is a homomorphism, is it true that $(\phi^{-1}(a))=\phi^{-1}((a))$?
Thanks

Comment: $\phi^{-1}(a)$ is not a single element in general.

Comment: adding to @lhf and if it is not the claim is false. $\phi:R^2\rightarrow R$ with $\phi(x,y) = x$, choose any non-trivial $R$ you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, e.g. for $(x)\subset \mathbb{Z/2 Z}[x]$ and $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}[x]\to\mathbb{Z/2 Z}[x]$ you get $\varphi^{-1}((x))=(2,x)$.